# Publish .Net library in COM using Wix Installer

Tags: wix, libraries, wix3.5, wix3.6

I'm trying to register a library on COM using WiX installer, but it seems to be ignoring me.

What I've tried so far is:

1. Used **heat.exe** to harvest all the info corresponding to the .dll.
2. Created a fragment containing all the information that I harvested from heat.exe.
   *I copied all the harvested information into a single component, to make things easier.*
3. I call the component using a `ComponentRef` that points to the component containing the related info for the dll to register.
4. I used a custom action to register it to the COM:

`<CustomAction Id="RegisterComLibrary" Directory="ComPublishDllFolder" ExeCommand="regsvr32.exe /s [ComPublishDllFolder]MyLibrary.dll />`

1. Insert the `CustomAction` in the `InstallExecuteSequence`:

   `<InstallExecuteSequence>
   <Custom Action="RegisterComLibrary" After="InstallFinalize">NOT Installed</Custom>
   </InstallExecuteSequence>`

But then, when I try to find the .dll in the COM using **oleview** or trying to use it with Visual Studio, I can't see it.

What I'm doing wrong?

NOTE: I'm getting the following message while trying to register it manually:

`The module "MyComObject.dll" was loaded but the call to DllRegisterServer failed.`

`Ensure that "MyComObject.dll" is a valid DLL or OCX and try again.`

Comment: What did heat produce? Also, calling `regsvr32` is not the Windows Installer way-It's designed to manage registry entries via the Registry table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, it was completely my fault. A misunderstanding of how .Net dlls published in COM work.

When I published my .Net compiled dll in COM and tried to use it in a .Net project, it launched a message saying that I can't use a COM library compiled in .Net, as it is a .Net library.

At first I thought it was a mistake, but actually, if I try to use the library in a C++ project (for example), it works fine.

The problem is that Visual Studio doesn't allow to consum COM libraries published in the same language that you built your project, apparently...

Comment: COM libraries do not have to be in DLLs that export DllRegisterServer. Those created with .NET usually are not.

Comment: If you want to use a .NET assembly in a .NET project, add the reference as a .NET assembly reference, not a COM reference.